# Unable to determine the principal end of an association - EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class "User" on which I have added the following fields:

```
    [Required]
    public int CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy_Id")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int? UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy_Id")]
    public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

When I try to push these fields into database with this command :

```
Add-Migration -Configuration DataModel.DevMigrations.Configuration TestAlterUser
```

I get this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'DataModel.Entities.User' and
>   'DataModel.Entities.User'.
>
> The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured
>   using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

If I remove the UpdatedBy property (or CreatedBy), it works perfectly.

The complete user's class :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy_Id")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int? UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy_Id")]
    public User UpdatedBy { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: what if you add inverse navigation property or configure your model to not look for inverse navigation properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy_Id")]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int? UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy_Id")]
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; } 

    //add these properties
    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> WereCreated {get; set;}
    [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> WereUpdated {get; set;}
}
```